# Why view is transparent during transition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, transition

I have a problem. When `UIView` with red `UILabel` is transitioning, it has transparent background. When transition has finished it has white background? Why? How to make always NOT transparent background? [image]

Comment: once check alpha value along with background color,id BGColor clear color then it'l happens after completion of transition view [placed on some otherview which has White BGColor.

Comment: @Balu alpha value 1.0f everywhere